# Use GanttChart in JavaScript notation

Tags: gwt, sapui5, gantt-chart

I'd like to use the Gantt chart control. I build the web application in combination with GWT, so I build everything in JavaScript instead of using the XML or other ways to have access to all controls out of GWT.

Now I have the problem that it looks like the GanttChartContainer class doesn't extend any other class like all the others (many extend from control, object and others), so I can't add it to any other control like a page for example. Is this information just missing in the documentation or how can I add it to an existing view?

Here's the documentation of this class:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.gantt.GanttChartContainer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that this is an error in the documentation. If you check this [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.gantt.GanttChartContainer/samples) and introspect the sources you see that GanttChartContainer extends [sap.ui.core.Control](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html).